Barn supports spans / strength
I am thinking about making more usable space (to me) in my new (to me) barn and while I know how to put up supports and a new header to reduce supports and increase the width of the column, I am lost when trying to ensure it will carry the load as well or preferably better.
I'll add a couple pictures and a screenshot with notes and measurements, but essentially the space had 7 supports but (as you can see in the pic or screenshot) support 3 has been removed and I would like to remove 3 more (#2, 5 and 6).  Originally, I was thinking 2x10's for the header and 2x6's for the supports like pictured but was also considering 3x2 rectangle steel 1/4" thick (header and supports).  Either way, I would also add corner supports (probably 4').  I'll stop here, hoping this makes some sense and answer any questions that might help.
Thanks,
Matt
p.s. I called the header truss in my spreadsheet screenshot.




Insulation on the roof makes me think of snow load.  Maybe a couple of inches or ten plus feet.  Deep snow is heavy.  Might want a local engineer/building contractor/inspector to advise you.

I live in Fruita, CO (high elevation desert climate) so we get a few inches, nothing like in the Rockies or back in my home state MN.  Thanks
